# Query last row with data in Google Sheet and set empty cells to "text"

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to query the last row with data of a Google sheet using Google Apps Script and set the empty cells to "Not Answered".

I got it working with one cell and could of course apply this to the other 10 as needed, but I'd like to loop through them since that would be more efficient.

Here is my single cell code that works.

```
function SetValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var certVal = ss.getRange(lastRow,5,1).getValues();

  if (certVal == ''){
ss.getRange(lastRow,5,1).setValue("Not Answered");
}

 Logger.log(certVal)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function checkLastRow() {
var ss =       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet =   ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());//Get last row and only that row.
var values = range.getValues()[0];//Get the defined ranges values
  Logger.log(values)
for (var i in values) {//Loop through each value
  Logger.log(values[i])
if (values[i] == "") {//Check to see if that value is blank.
 values[i] = "Not Answered";
}

}//Outside the loop so it has finished and is holding all the changed values.
range.setValues([values]);//Write all the values back to the sheet with changes.
}
```

.getRange() has several parameter options, here we are using a very dynamic one.
(row to start on, column to start on, how many rows to get, how many columns to get)
this only defines the  range we want.

.getValues() returns the the defined range actual values. Because we are only getting one row or data is why [0] is used on the end, to go ahead and get the array of the cells. The logger would show this.  If you only use .getValues() it would like this [[cell1],[cell2]]. By using the [0] it returns just the cell values [cell1],[cell2] so they can be iterated through individually.

The for loop is basically reading.

```
for (var i = 0; and i is <= values.length//the number of cells returned with getValues..; i++//everytime the loop gets to the end increase i by 1) {
  perform action during loop on current object.(values[i])
}
```

The way it is written above is a shorthand. for (var i in values){}.

The for loop allows to look at each cell individually that is returned from that whole row.
so every time it loops and i increases by 1, it's looking at the value of the next cell. So it looks something like this.
Remember i is changing each time but it is an integer.

```
Loop 1(values[0] = cell1)
Loop 2(values[1] = cell2)
Lopp 3(values[2] = cell3)
```

So we use the "if statement to test a value" it is always looking a true or false.

```
if (values[i] == "")// if current cell is equal to blank then 
{do something here if true}
```

The next step can be hard to grasp sometimes, but because the script has the values, you can change them on the fly by defining which object you want and using = to change it.
So above it knows the current cell the script is on, and because it's inside the if statement it only runs if the original value is blank. So it' simply changes to "Not Answered"

the variable "range" defines the area we want already, so just call it again, and use the setValues() to return all the values with the changes that were made.

Comment: I get this error with that Lenny.  Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 12)

Comment: Sorry should be in brackets range.setValues([values]);

Comment: That didn't work Lenny, it didn't error out but it didn't write anything to the sheet.  I logged for values and the log show the column names in row 1.

Comment: I'm sorry Dave, just edited and updated the code, that should work for you.

Comment: Yes that worked Lenny, thank you so much.  My brute force solution was going to take alot of lines of code and I knew there should be a more efficient way of doing this.  Would you mind commenting your code, Lines 4, 5, 7, 9 and 14?  It'd be helpful for this newby and I'm sure others that will use this post.  Thanks again for the help.  GREAT solution...

Comment: Dave hopefully those comments and further explination help.